# Is it possible to use Azure AD B2C authentication via its API?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

**Context**

I've successfully created and configured a Azure B2C tenant and a ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web Application which uses AD B2C built in workflows to authenticate users.

**Question**

In the application described above the login forms (even they have customized design by me) are provided and hosted by Azure AD B2C infrastructure.

Is it possible to use my entirely custom login form (hosted in my web app), get the typed credentials from the uses, then call Azure AD B2C API to do the authentication, and get the token?... or it is not a supported scenario and asking for the credentials form is always must be hosted by the Azure AD B2C infrastructure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a web app this is not supported. We do support an [ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc?tabs=applications) from mobile apps.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. What about Azure AD (not AD B2C)? I mean is it possible to authenticate Azure AD school or work accounts via API and not via the provided built in UI?

Comment: I believe the same answer applies to AAD.

Comment: Correct. The same applies to ADFS. For all of these, you have to use the Microsoft supplied login page.

Comment: thx for all. Would be useful to update this Q/A if anything changes in the future

Comment: Just a late afterthought: is it possible to have a web app, using ROPC in browser side via javascript, then having a token or something and an ASP.NET Core server app which takes that token as a proof of identity? (just like an API application) This way we can have completly self implemented UI for the username and password input, all the authentication request coming from different client IP to Azure, so its ROPS security mechanism will not think it is atteck?

Comment: No, because that will get blocked by CORS